# Meaning of "To be"

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of  "to be hiered" ? Whether it means the person is hiered or he is yet to be hiered?

Comment: Do you mean the verb *to hire*? As in the expression "to be hired"? The question needs more context. Where did you read this notice/sign/message/announcement? We need to know if we are talking about a person or an object, things can be hired = rented.

Comment: Is it possible OP means _heired_, as in _inherited_?  This is a very rare use, but is a verb as shown at this [link] (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heired) #5.

Answer (score 1):

**Be to be** is a construction with various different meanings.

(1) a command:

> Safety helmets **are to be** worn at all times.
>
> Safety helmets **must be** worn at all times.

(2) 'are [here] [/ provided] for the purpose of':

> These cakes **are** [here] **to be** eaten.
>
> **The reason** these cakes have been put here **is so that you can** eat them.
>   Please help yourselves.

(3) 'are available for'

> These trees **are** [here] **to be** used for firewood.
>
> We can chop down these trees for firewood.

(4) 'are going to be' [/ 'It is intended that']

> 200 dockworkers **are to be** employed.
>
> [It is intended that] 200 dockworkers **are going to be** employed.

As others say, which usage is intended isn't clear here.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

**We need to hire two workers.**

and

**We need two workers to be hired.**

They convey the same desired result.  The first implies it is our responsibility to perform the hiring.  The second does not have that assumed responsibility.

Comment: hiered may not be a misspelling

Comment: @James  Assuming the spelling is correct.........is my interpretation of the difference correct??